# Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I cannot figure out why this issue is occuring. Need some solutions.

[image: Event]

[image: Error]

Comment: `const btn` is initialized with the return value of the call of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the button you should use:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("get-data-button");
btn.disabled = true;
```

What you are doing now is, you save the return of `addEventListener` in you variable `btn`. But this function returns nothing.

After setting the variable `btn` with `document.getElementById("get-data-button")` you can also add the eventlistener like this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click',getUserData);
```